# Is it possible to replace an hour in a date with another time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is it possible to replace the time from 'this.state.date' to an hour from `this.state.time`
`23:46:58` -> change on `00: 02: 00`

```
this.state {
  date: Thu Jun 27 2019 23:46:58 GMT+0200 
  second: 120
}

moment().startOf(this.state.date).seconds(this.state.second).format('HH:mm:ss');

//Output: Thu Jun 27 2019 00:02:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: so you are adding 15min+ to the current date?

Comment: No. example replace time from this.state.date(23:46:58) to `00:02:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `moment` to do this, it's very simple with [`Date.prototype.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

```
this.setState(({ date, second }) => {
  date.setHours(0, 0, second);
  return { date };
});
```

```js
const date = new Date();

date.setHours(0, 0, 120);
console.log(date.toString());
```